# Get previous value of a SWT Combo when selecting a new value

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT combo with a selection listener:

```
myCombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(myCombo.getText());
    }
});
```

`myCombo.getText()` will return the value that was just selected, is there a way to select the previous value? maybe using the `SelectionEvent`?

Comment: The listener should save the selection in an instance variable (of the class containing the combo), having initialized it as null.

Comment: but that would require having an instance variable for each combo, I was hoping to get the value from the event to avoid creating lots of instance variables as I have a lot of combos

Comment: write your own ComboBox class that extends Combo, and save it as an instance variable of that class. Then add a getPreviousSelection() method to that class, and use that class instead of Combo.